# Will jQuery or Prototype be better?

Tags: jquery, prototypejs

I am a new to software development. I have doubt, regarding which JavaScript library I should select for my new project, which is a small website with rich user interface. [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) and  [Prototype](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_JavaScript_Framework) are the two options in my mind.

Will I go with jQuery or Prototype?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/176324

Answer (score 4):

Choose the one you know better.

Answer (score 2):

I will vote for jQuery. It gives more flexibility from the programming end.

Answer (score 2):

I'd go for jQuery. I used both, but IMO jQuery has a nicer API (easier to learn).